# How to modify the fonts of the \paragraph in classic thesis?

Tags: paragraphs, classicthesis

I'm currently writing my thesis with `classicthesis` and I would like to modify the fonts of the `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` commands in order to have them with my current font Minion pro. How could I dot that ? This is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,twoside=semi,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph} Some text.
\subparagraph{A subparagraph}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `classicthesis` package doesn't support `\subparagraph`. If you *really* need five sectioning levels under `\chapter` (which I don't believe), you can add a similar setting as `\paragraph`:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  openany,
  twoside=semi,
  footinclude=true,
  headinclude=true
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize}
  {\thesubparagraph}
  {0pt}
  {\spacedlowsmallcaps}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph} Some text.
\subparagraph{A subparagraph} Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine. But as I do need five sectioning levels, if you have any suggestion, please feel free to tell me what and how.